# How can I decrypt an RSA cipher knowing only p and q?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, rsa

Knowing only p and q, how can I definitively find e and d in order to be able to decrypt the ciphertext?

Comment: I used this fancy new search engine called  "google" to search for "RSA algorithm" and it gave me about 1.06 million results... Give it a try!

Comment: I am well aware of the RSA algorithm. However, I can't find a way to determine e and d with certainty given only p and q. There are many results on google about decrypting RSA, but they all seem to assume that you know p, q AND e. If you can find any result among your 1.06 million ones that actually deals with the situation I have and point me to it, then your response might actually be useful.

Comment: Your question has to be useful first

Answer (score 0):

Given that you are "well aware" of the RSA algorithm (I'm assuming textbook RSA) then you are probably also aware that e can be chosen as any value between 1 and φ(n), provided both e and φ(n) are co-prime.

If your question boils down to *Can I determine, with 100% certainty, the values of e and d given only p and q?* then the answer is **no**.

This is because any valid value of e selected will decrypt the ciphertext to something, not neccessarily the original, but to something.  You'd have to have some indication of the plaintext's context, e.g. is it English?  If you knew this, and provided p and q were relatively small, you **could** test possible values of e until you received a result in English.

In practice, e is often chosen as 3 or 65537.

Comment: My question was indeed whether I could determine them with certainly as it did not seem possible by looking at the algorithm, yet this was all the information available in the problem. I assumed I was missing something. Thanks for clearing that up. The result is supposed to be a credit card number, so as long as the plaintext is all digits, it should be correct ( though unlike English, I can't be sure there aren't other combination of possible combinations of digits ). The possible values of e are helpful, as they make the problem solvable. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: @BrandonHeat Sounds like a classic assignment problem, never enough information!  Good luck.